# Very strange php include behavior..

Tags: php, include, cross-domain

I am experiencing some very strange behavior when including a php file. 
I need to load a script that is not on the same domain as the page that will be calling it. 

I have already created a system that works using cURL, but I just recently found out that many of the sites that will need to have access to this script, do not have cURL installed.
I did, however, notice that these sites have `allow_url_fopen` set to `on`. With this knowledge I got started creating a new system that would let me just include the script on the remote site.


Just testing this out, I coded the script `test.php` as follows:

```
<?php 
echo("test");
?>
```

I include this script on the remote page using:

```
<?php
include("http://mydomain.com/script.php");
?>
```

and it works no problem and "test" is printed at the top of the page.


However, if I add a function to the script and try to call the function from the page, it crashes.
To make it worse, this site has php errors turned off and I have no way of turning it on.

To fully make sure that I didn't just mess up the code, I made my `test.php` look like this:

```
<?php
function myfunc()
{
return "abc";
}
?>
```

Then on the page including the file:

```
<?php 
include("http://mydomain.com/script.php");
echo(myfunc());
?>
```

And it crashes.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not odd behavior, but since you load the file over the internet (note in this case the World Wide Web), the file is interpreted before it is sent to your include function.

Since the script is interpreted no functions will be visible, but only the output of the script.

Either load it over FTP or create an API for the functions.

Comment: Ah, okay that makes sense. I will look into creating an API. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess: The PHP of `http://mydomain.com/script.php` is **interpreted** by the web server of mydomain.com. All you're `including` is the *result* of that script. For a simple `echo("test")`, that's "test". Functions do not produce any output and are not made available to the `including` script. Confirm this by simply visiting `http://mydomain.com/script.php` in your browser and see what you get. You would need to stop mydomain.com from actually interpreting the PHP file and just returning it as pure text.

**But:** this sounds like a bad idea to begin with. Cross-domain includes are an anti-patterns. Not only does it open you up to security problems, it also makes every page load unnecessarily slow. If cross-domain inclusions is the answer, your question is wrong.

Comment: Yeah that must be the problem. I realize that it is not a very good idea to do cross-domain includes, but I am having a hard time seeing how it could be exploited in my case.  What is the difference between a server calling my script and somebody just loading the script in their browser?  From what I can tell, the big no no is setting allow_url_fopen to on in the first place, which I am not doing. The client already has this set on their server. I do see how it could make the pages load slower than usual though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible exploits include: first of all, the code you're including, by definition, is publicly visible. I don't know what you're using this technique for, but often people try to keep certain files "secret" on their server, which in this case has the exact opposite effect. Other exploits: DNS attacks against the server which redirects requests to `mydomain.com` somewhere else, conveniently allowing arbitrary code injection. Or just hijacking of the `mydomain.com` server in the first place.

Comment: What if I am able to keep anything "secret" off of this particular script? The script will be pulling information from a mysql database, but if I put the code to connect to the database in a separate file, and include that on the script, then won't that information still be hidden? And other than the information to directly connect to my database, the information that the script will pull is in no way "secret", nor would it be useful to anybody. Are the DNS exploits alone enough to make this not a viable solution though?

Comment: The added delay alone would make this not a viable solution. The other details just add more minus points. And I don't know what will be included in the final file, but whatever you want to `include`, it will need to be transferred over HTTP in clear text and anybody can simply go to the URL to see the code that's going to be included. Make an API that transfers only the needed data, if at all.

Comment: Okay, I will admit to defeat and give up using this method. :P Are there any problems using cURL to do this? Or is there anything I need to be careful of when using cURL like this?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you want to do with curl. Don't use it to fetch and execute arbitrary code over the 'net, whether you do that using `include` or curl doesn't matter.

Comment: I would be passing variables that my server would use to pull information out of a database and send back.

Answer (score 0):

You are including the client side output from test.php rather than the server-side source code. Rename test.php to test.phpc to prevent executing the script. However this is dangerous out of security point of view.